# Powershell select XML nodes where attribute contained in array

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

Say I have structures like:

```
[xml]$i = "
<root>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <data>Content_Of_1</data>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <data>Content_Of_2</data>
<item>
    <id>5</id>
    <data>Content_Of_5</data>
</item>
    </item>
</root>
"

$foo = @(1,2,3)
```

And I want to select $i.root.item.data where $i.root.item.id is in $foo.

To select the nodes matching IDs in the array I can do:

```
($i.root.item | ? {$foo -contains $_.id})
```

But for some reason if I try to get at $_.data, I get nothing:

```
($i.root.item | ? {$foo -contains $_.id}).data
```

Why?

Comment: Are you sure about the xpath tag?

Comment: Original phrasing invited alternative xpath solutions. I have since got close w/o xpath, but xpath solutions stil welcome.

Comment: First of all replace you item tag by "items", as far as I remember it exists a problem linked with the fact that "item" is already used as an object property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But for some reason if I try to get at $_.data, I get nothing:

```
($i.root.item | ? {$foo -contains $_.id}).data
```

The reason you get nothing is you are trying to access a property (data) on the whole **collection** where it does not exist. You need to do the following:

```
$i.root.item | ? {$foo -contains $_.id} | ForEach-Object { $_.data }
```

Which accesses the data property on **each** object. 
You could also select the values in the data property for each object:

```
$i.root.item | ? {$foo -contains $_.id} | Select-Object data
```

Which would produce an array of PSCustomObjects where each object would contain a single property named data (as opposed to a string array as the ForEach-Object example would).

Note that in Powershell 3.0, with the new property enumeration feature, your original syntax would produce the desired result as the enumeration would automatically be done.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to do this without a foreach loop?

Comment: @Yevgeniy - updated answer with option of using Select-Object.